# How to prevent a nest thermostat from auto updating its firmware

Tags: software, over-the-air-updates, nest-thermostat

I am having a problem where my nest thermostat doesn’t pre-heat until someone is home because we are using the home/away assist feature that sets the heat level to an “eco” temperature when no one is home. I want to take advantage of home/away assist to save energy when no one is home, but I want scheduled temperatures to override this and begin pre heating on a schedule. As [this support post mentions, this used to be the behavior, but a software update changed it](https://www.nest-community.com/s/question/0D51W00005HNMb9SAH/why-is-my-nest-not-heating-the-house-when-scheduled).

I contacted nest support and asked them if I could use home/away assist and also have scheduled temperatures override the eco mode. They said no. I asked if I could downgrade the software on my thermostat. They said no - the software is automatically upgraded from the nest servers, and there is no way to turn this off.

I read on reddit about [an option to do a factory reset and disconnecting from Wi-fi to disable automatic upgrades](https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/Nest/comments/96dpyv/downgrading_nest_thermostat_software/). However, I want to also be able to adjust my thermostat settings over the Internet.

Is there a way, perhaps involving some hardware hacking or a firewall, to achieve this by doing a factory reset and blocking the auto software updates?

**Update**

I found [this description of the Nest Thermostat API from 2012](https://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/1754). Not sure if it is current and also not sure how to block only software updates without blocking thermostat adjustments I send over the Internet.

Comment: blacklist the nest server IP in your router config

Comment: You probably don't if you want it to continue to do anything remotely useful

Comment: @jsotola I still want to be able to adjust my thermostat settings remotely over the internet. How might I block only the software updates? I also updated the question with a link to a description of how the Nest Thermostat API works

Comment: From a general security point of view, firmware updates need to be automatic, and roll-back prevented. So even if there is a workaround for this specific product/version, that is just another security flaw that ought to be closed in the future.

Answer (score 3):

I just used [Stringify](https://www.stringify.com/) to up the house temperature one hour before I get home every day. Works good.

Comment: Please edit this answer to include a lot more context and may be a link to what ever Stringify is.